# Why does my NetBeans 11.2 IDE freeze upon startup and how do I fix it?

Tags: netbeans, startup, freeze, netbeans-11

**This question has been asked before, most of them (if not all) however are 4 years or older and do not concern the 11.2 build specifically.**

My issue is pretty much as the title says. 8/10 times I open up my NetBeans IDE, it freezes shortly after starting up. Typically while it says it's in the process of "Background scanning of projects...".

I've tried several things without any luck. These include:

1. Clear the cache folder inside `C:\Users\malthe.w\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache`
2. Close NetBeans, move project folders out to a different location and reopen NetBeans.
3. Only have one project open at a time (meaning closing all unused projects).
4. Disabling unused plugins.

My workaround at the moment is to restart my laptop entirely, which is not a very viable solution considering how often my NetBeans suddenly freezes indefinitely in the middle of work.

One thing to note is that during every startup, NetBeans insists on opening old tabs from old projects, even though they have been closed previously.

I'd be happy to provide some logs of some kind, I just don't know where to find them. So please let me know if needed.

**Edit:**

Laptop Specs:

- Intel Core i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz 1.80GHz
- 8,00 GB RAM
- Windows 10 Home Version 1909, OS build 18363.720, x64-based processor

Here's my NetBeans 11.2 log file: https://pastebin.com/S631dbfk

I'm using JDK 8.0 with NetBeans 11.2.

Can't really see what exactly the problem is in the logs, but I guess memory could be the issue. Thing is I just have a lot of peers with the same or less amount of RAM that I have, but their NetBeans works just fine.

Comment: [1] Your actions so far are all helpful (though obviously not enough!). [2] Since the problem is intermittent and is resolved by rebooting, is it possible that you simply don't have enough memory on your laptop? [3] Please update your question with the NetBeans log. If NetBeans starts you can display it using **View > IDE Log**, but you need to access that file directly if NetBeans freezes. See [Where do I find the NetBeans log...](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile) for more details. [4] Update your question with the JDK version used by NetBeans. (You can't use JDK 14 with 11.2!)

Comment: @skomisa Hi there, sorry for the late reply. I'm still having the same issue. I have updated my question with more info, including a link to the log file. Would really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: [1] You are running with update 111 for JDK 8 (8u111) which is from 2016! NetBeans 11.x documentation doesn't specify any particular update requirement for JDK 8, but I'd suggest using a more recent JDK 8 update for bug and security fixes. Or even better, upgrade to JDK 11 if possible. But if your peers are also using 8u111 this is probably not relevant for your freezes. [2] Next time NetBeans freezes go to Windows Task Manager (CTL/ALT/DEL, then select _Task Manager_), click the _Performance_ tab and then click _Memory_. This may give you a rough idea of whether lack of memory is an issue.

Comment: [3] Was the NetBeans log you posted taken after a freeze? If not, could you replace the existing log in your question with one taken after a freeze? [4] One more thing to try  (which is just a wild guess): **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Files >** uncheck the *Enable auto-scanning of sources* checkbox,and restart NetBeans. That should prevent _"GitInterceptor.refreshTask: Scanning in progress"_ . See https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/enable-auto-scanning-of-sources-scan-for-external-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Problem seemed to be with the version of Windows I was running (Windows 10 Home), as completely reinstalling Windows 10 (Enterprise version) managed to fix the issue.